# I am new to springboot and need to insert json data in oracle table and avoid duplicate inserts

Tags: java, sql, json, oracle, spring-boot

I am able to insert the json data in oracle table using intermediate table from springboot

I have a table abc-

```
ID  first_name  last_name  cust_ID  Active_Ind last_upd_dt
1   abc         pqr          101     Y          01-Apr-2021
2   aaa         bbb          102     Y          05-Feb-2021
```

I need to make sure-
If the new json data has the above existing value, do not update table abc, keep it as is and if it has new record only then insert. And if the oracle table record is not present in new json data, then change the ACTIVE_IND to 'N'

I tried the below query to insert value where not exists from intermediate table 'test':

```
insert into abc
(ID, 
first_name, 
last_name, 
cust_ID, 
active_ind, 
last_upd_dt)
select 
abc_seq.nextval,
first_name, 
last_name, 
cust_ID, 
active_ind, 
last_upd_dt 
from test t
where not exists(
select null from abc a
where a.fist_name = t.first_name
and a.cust_ID = t.cust_ID);
```

This works fine in Oracle developer, but when I try the below query in springboot, it somehow inserts duplicates, not sure why it is happening, I have used prepared statement for the index.

````
insert into abc
(ID, 
first_name, 
last_name, 
cust_ID, 
active_ind, 
last_upd_dt)
select 
abc_seq.nextval,
?, 
?, 
?, 
?, 
?
from test t
where not exists(
select null from abc a
where a.fist_name = t.first_name
and a.cust_ID = t.cust_ID);```

I have tried merge queries as well, but none of them worked for me.
````

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot I'm assuming you have mapped entities and you are using JPA.

Once you mapped the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc")
public class ABC {

   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
   
   ...
}
```

Then I also assume you created a Repository (if you are using the Repo pattern)

```
public interface ABCRepository extends JpaRepository<ABC, Long> {

   //leave it blank If you don't need any particular method for querying
}
```

In this case you can use the findOne JPA method passing the Example of the object that you want the result to match. If it's just the ID then simply use the findByID. Anyways, you can now create yourself a saveIfExists(Example example)

```
public ABC saveIfNotExists(Example<ABC> example) {
   return abcRepo.findOne(example).orElse(()-> {
     return abcRepo.save(example);
   };
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am using JdbcItemReader and Writer for this. I used ignore_row_on_dupkey_index and that worked fine eignore the duplicates. Initially it was giving unique constraint violated error, but this worked out. Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad you found your own way out!